# Google Pay Payment Integration

Tags: payment-gateway, google-pay

I want to integrate Google Pay payment into my project. I have gone through the tutorials on https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial

Now my scenario is:

I have 3 parties: App Owner, Store Owner, and Customer

**App Owner**: Provides an aggregator platform which brings together all store owner and provides them with an opportunity to sale their products and in return get some percentage of commission.

**Store Owner**: Sales the product to the end customer through an app owner's platform.

**End Customer**: Buys a product that belongs to the store owner via the app owner platform and completes the payment.

***Example***: Customer purchases 100 RS worth of product

App owner's commission is 10 RS which gets credited to his a/c
90 RS will get into store owner a/c

So basically here payment is done in 2 parts. One for the store aggregator who is an app owner and another is for the store owner.

So I want to understand that Is this possible by making use of Google Pay Integration? Can we split the payment across multiple accounts?

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mahendra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've described isn't automatically possible out of the box with Google Pay. You would need to do this manually.

The relationship exists between Google Pay and the merchant (the app owner in your case). The app owner would charge the customer the full amount and then be responsible for charging commission and dispersing the funds the the store owner.

One thing to note is the Google Pay doesn't actually process the payment, it facilitates the payment by making it easy for users to choose a saved payment method. To process the payment you will need to use a [supported payment processor](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/#participating-processors). You would need to find a way to disperse the funds to the store owners (example, a monthly bank transfer).

I haven't used this myself, but [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) may help with this.

Comment: Hey @Soc thanks for the response. It is indeed helpful.

Comment: No problem. Please let us know how you go about solving this. I'm sure other people will be interested in the outcome.

Comment: We are heading with Stripe Connect only. Accepted the answer as well.

Comment: @Soc I'm also working on similar application just we are not taking any commission. So the transaction will be directly between store owner and customer. I want to know, in this kind of system can app owner (me) as a mediator between store owner and customer will be able to store the transaction information in app database as the transaction is between store owner and customer without any legal issue. I'm going to use google pay without gateway.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of this depends on your specific scenario. If the customer is paying the store owner directly, then each store owner will need to be onboarded as a merchant individually. Alternatively, if the customer is paying you (the app owner) and you're dispersing the funds, then only you need to be onboarded as a merchant and you can disperse to as many additional stores as you like.